# How to attach div to cursor each time window scrolls

Tags: javascript

I've just started programming a few months ago and I am very new to the language. 
I wanted to make a custom cursor and I found this code that works perfectly. The only problem is that when scrolling the Custom cursor sticks to de background and scrolls with the body. It doesn't look natural as it should stick in place. What am i missing here?
Thanks

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    //attach div to cursor each time mouse moves
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        $(".custom-cursor").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
    });

    //attempt to attach div to cursor each time window scrolls

    $(document).on('scroll', function(e){
           $(".custom-cursor").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
    });


//change cursor over menu
$('body a').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.custom-cursor').removeClass('activemenu');
});
```

});

Comment: If your cursor is (or can be made into) an image/cur file, why don't you just use the [CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) `cursor: url(custom.cur),auto;`? Pure CSS will almost always outperform a JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting your cursor div to `position: fixed` should do the trick.

EDIT:
As another user commented, `cursor: url(custom.cur),auto;` is the better solution obviously.  You're doing a lot of unnecessary js operations otherwise.